# Magento 2: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry in category page

Tags: magento2

I getting below error while open category page.
i also tried to reindexing, cache clear, setup upgrade and di:compile but its not working.

Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '62332' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5b3a22e6d14c03_14202655` (`entity_id`,`score`) VALUES

Comment: Take a backup of this table and try to check to remove this entry and do reindexing, cache clear, setup upgrade and di:compile again.

Comment: this table is not exists in database, its temp storage table.

Comment: Try to reset search indexing and try again.

Comment: ok let me try to reset and reindex

Comment: @PareshaU its not working.

Comment: just give your help for solving a issue instead of solve question grammar issue.

Comment: Did you ever get it?

Comment: @tjjen not yet.

Comment: try in private window or clearing browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a   \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::REPLACE directive
in magento/framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/TemporaryStorage.php
 in the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's magento bug you can follow here to get more info: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025762211-503-error-on-store-front-catalog-pages-with-Integrity-constraint-violation-in-logs